# Migration from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.1 toLocalIterator throwing error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I have migrated my working code base from spark 1.6 to 2.1. There was an error while running my code. It showing error while i'm using toLocalIterator method for RDD. I tried to get glue from error log doesn't seems to be work.

```
logger.info("Generating common words started!.")
logger.info("Reading from mongo db")
mongo_db = MongoDBConnector()
logger.info("Connecting to mongo database.")
db = mongo_db.connect_database()
logger.info("Update lda_vector of all_documents to default value -1.")
mongo_db.update_lda_vector(db, passive_article)
logger.info("Getting documents from mongo datbase to train.")
records = mongo_db.get_documents(db, passive_article, years=0, days=2)
logger.info("Parallel data for spark execution.")
rdd_records = sparkContext.parallelize(records)
logger.info("Total number of records: " + str(rdd_records.count()))
logger.info("Spark map and parse documents")
rdd_cached_docs = rdd_records.map(parse_required_data).map(tokenize_text).map(remove_stopwords).map(
    remove_common_words).map(filter_token_using_pos_tgs)
rdd_cached_list = rdd_cached_docs.map(lambda data_tuple: data_tuple[1]).flatMap(
    lambda data: [porter_stemmer.value.stem(i) for i in data])
logger.info("Generating the word list from tokenized text")
logger.info("Total word list count "+str(rdd_cached_list.count()))
word_list = list(rdd_cached_list.toLocalIterator())
```

Error Logs

```
17/03/02 18:03:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 2.0
(TID 8, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 580886 bytes)
    17/03/02 18:03:45 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 8)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/st701am/projects/recs/spark/lda_builder.py", line 257, in <module>
        pre_process_documents(passive_article)
      File "/home/st701am/projects/recs/spark/lda_builder.py", line 108, in pre_process_documents
        word_list = list(rdd_cached_list.toLocalIterator())
      File "/opt/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 140, in _load_from_socket
      File "/opt/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 144, in load_stream
      File "/opt/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 161, in _read_with_length
      File "/opt/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 555, in read_int
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    socket.timeout: timed out
    17/03/02 18:03:48 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
    17/03/02 18:03:48 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.28.20.110:4040
    17/03/02 18:03:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 failed: toLocalIterator at /home/st701am/projects/recs/spark/lda_builder.py:108, took 3.813652 s
    17/03/02 18:03:48 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (toLocalIterator at /home/st701am/projects/recs/spark/lda_builder.py:108) failed in 3.806 s due to Stage cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    17/03/02 18:03:48 ERROR PythonRDD: Error while sending iterator
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 2 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:808)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:806)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using `toLocalIterator` on 2.0 and I found that if I cache RDD then timeouts disappear. Try replacing

```
logger.info("Total word list count "+str(rdd_cached_list.count()))
word_list = list(rdd_cached_list.toLocalIterator())
```

with:

```
rdd_cached_list.cache()
logger.info("Total word list count "+str(rdd_cached_list.count()))
word_list = list(rdd_cached_list.toLocalIterator())
```

But why are you using `list(iterator)`? Wouldn't be easier to just `collect` rdd?